# Is this code vulnerable to DOM XSS?

Tags: xss

```
const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');

// Set the source (src) attribute
scriptElement.src = '/evil.js?'+decodeURI(urlParams['sync']);

// Append the script element to the HTML document
document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

Can I not inject `">` and break out of the src attribute?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot manipulate the HTML structure through the `sync` parameter, because the `src` property of the JavaScript `HTMLScriptElement` object has the sole purpose of programmatically setting the source URL of this element. The string does not get parsed as HTML markup, so characters like `"` or `>` are taken as literal text within the URL and have no special meaning.

You will need a JavaScript feature which lets you manipulate HTML like the `innerHTML` property or `document.write`.

Note that I'm assuming the `evil.js` part of the URL is fixed by the website owner. If you as the attacker can set the entire URL, then you can of course inject arbitrary JavaScript code through the script element.